# I file contains comma for separation but I want them to be in different line

Tags: notepad++

My file looks like

my text,my text,my text

I want it to look like

my text

my text

my text

Comment: your question and examples are two different stories. Better write a question or examples

Comment: Does it help understanding please do tell me if it does

Comment: now everything is clear

Comment: Hi bro I hope I am not disturbing you but I changed my question and I hope I made it easy to answer now could you help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

check this solution - it may not be perfect

Comment: Thanks and Both Answers were correct and \r created an extra blank line so I removed it and now It is giving me the perfect output thanks a lot